# Populate a slideshow list of images from images in a wordpress page?

Tags: images, slideshow

I'm using the "flexise" slideshow script to automatically scroll a list of images. The list is hard-coded along with the script in a wordpress template page.

While this works fine, how could you make it so that the slideshow pulled any images added to a special (private) wordpress page instead of having to add each img src manually??

```
 <ul id="flexiselDemo3">
 <li><img src="http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/logo.png" /></li>
 <li><img src="http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/logo2.png" /></li>
 <li><img src="http://mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/logo3.png" /></li>
 </ul>
```

Many thanks

Trying your suggestion now, I've replaced the above with this:

```
$attachments = get_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_status' =>'any',
// This is where you specify the ID of your private image page
'post_parent' => 6909,
));

if (count($attachments)) {
// We have attachments
?>
<ul id="flexiselDemo3">
    <?php
    // Now we loop through them
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'full'); ?>
        </li>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</ul>
<?php
}
```

But it's throwing an error. Probably something simple, but I'm not experienced enough to debug?

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home4/speedyp/public_html  /speedypancake.com/tmc/wp-content/themes/sirens/page_f.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of this is part of the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Show_attachments_for_the_current_post):

```
<?php
$attachments = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' =>'any',
    // This is where you specify the ID of your private image page
    'post_parent' => $private_page_id,
));

if (count($attachments)) {
    // We have attachments
    ?>
    <ul id="flexiselDemo3">
        <?php
        // Now we loop through them
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
            ?>
            <li>
                <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'full'); ?>
            </li>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping tf. Still very new with wp - I would add that code in the template page?

The $private_page_id might be $185  ie. the dollar sign followed by the page id number??

Comment: **Yes**, you would **add the above code** directly where your **hard-coded list** is. And **no**, there is no need for a `$` if you specify the value. If your page ID is 185, then it's **just `'post_parent' => 185,`**.

Comment: Thanks again - I've updated my question using your suggestion and an error code

Comment: Well, okay, sorry, my bad. You have to wrap the code in between `<?php` and `?>` of course. I updated my answer.

Comment: tf - You are lucky this is the internet, or I would give you a great big kiss X! Please accept my sincere thanks instead. This is going to help me enormously :)